# Is there a tmux version of screen's zombie mode?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

`screen` has a feature called Zombie Mode, which makes it so that when the process of a screen (window or pane, in `tmux` terminology) dies, the window doesn't close - it just stays there until restarted, as opposed to closing. Is there a way to do this in `tmux`?

My use-case is that I start a number of local development servers in different panes in my `tmux.conf`, but if I have to `C-c` one of them to restart it, I don't want that pane to vanish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set set-remain-on-exit on` keeps the window/pane from closing, and `bind-key r respawn-window` causes `C-b r` to restart the process.

Comment: `set-remain-on-exit` was removed in `tmux` 2.4 - see https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/787 for details on how to do this now